# Notify different users by id after batch write to a collection with cloud functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, notifications

I have a collection I am making a batch write to in Cloud Firestore using typescript. I want to create a function to notify each user after they are added to the collection with the batch write.This is my code

```
   `const batch = db.batch();
    itemArray.forEach((item: any) => {
    const docRef = db.collection("user").doc();
    const userObject = {
    id: docRef.id,
    user: {
    userId: item.userId,
    name: item.name,
    },
    };
    batch.set(docRef, userObject);
    });
              
    await batch.commit();`
```

Comment: Where is this all happening? In a Cloud function or client side? Also are you referring to Firebase Cloud Messaging for sending notifications ?

Comment: it's happening in a cloud function. And I don't know about using cloud messaging. Any suggestion to arrive at a solution will be appreciated

Comment: How do you want to "notify" users? Also is this an Android App or Web?

Comment: it is a flutter app.